# Should I run mod_fcgi or APC on a 512MB VPS?

Tags: apache2

Considering that I run a low memory VPS, should I configure Apache to use mod_fcgi, PHP APC or both? As I understand it, the APC will not be shared between processes so I wonder what would produce the best result on busy sites: mod_fcgi, APC or a combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use both fcgi and APC -- they don't do the same thing at all. But 512MB of RAM is not enough for a busy site.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference, but I wonder if the resource overhead of running APC+fcgi is worth it compared to APC+mod_php or only fcgi

Comment: APC+fcgi will use less resources than APC+mod_php, because Apache won't have to load PHP into memory for serving static content like images and stylesheets. (I'm assuming you're using the Apache prefork MPM, since while worker will save memory, it may well fall over from time to time if you have any non-threadsafe code).